# babel, webpack with nodemon script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, build-tools

I was wondering if there is a way to configure webpack with babel and nodemon. I I pretty much searched the web but found nothing helpful or it may be me because i am pretty much new to build tools.
I have this script in my `package.json`:

```
"start": "nodemon app.js --exec babel-node"
```

It transpile my code and also restart the server when there is changes. I was wondering if there is such configuration for webpack with the watch functionality. Can i do it with webpack (run the server and watch for changes and restart along with the babel transpile) ?

Comment: You normally don't use Webpack for the server part, it's more targeted towards bundling client-side assets such as browser JS, CSS, images, etc. Is there any particular reason why you would like to use Webpack for the server?

Comment: there are perfectly good reasons for using webpack for the server, for example if you do server-side compilation of React components

Comment: @PatrickHund: You're right, but since OP is new to build tools, I'm just trying to make sure they know why they're using it :)

Comment: I am trying to build a basic app with what i am learning, yes in some point in near future i am going to use react also. so i thought i would learn how to use a build tool as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use nodemon, you can use [webpack's watch feature](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/).

Here's an example script, let's call it `backend-dev.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const compiler = webpack({
    // add your webpack configuration here
});
const watchConfig = {
    // compiler watch configuration
    // see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000
};

let serverControl;

compiler.watch(watchConfig, (err, stats) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.stack || err);
        if (err.details) {
            console.error(err.details);
        }
        return;
    }

    const info = stats.toJson();

    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
        info.errors.forEach(message => console.log(message));
        return;
    }

    if (stats.hasWarnings()) {
        info.warnings.forEach(message => console.log(message));
    }

    if (serverControl) {
        serverControl.kill();
    }

    // change app.js to the relative path to the bundle created by webpack, if necessary
    serverControl = spawn('node', [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app.js')]);

    serverControl.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
    serverControl.stderr.on('data', data => console.error(data.toString()));
});
```

You can start this script on the command line with

```
node backend-dev.js
```

When you make changes in your server code, webpack will recompile and restart your server.

Comment: Is it possible to do any kind of config in webpack so that it watches for my development files for changes and when there is changes it updates the bundle file and run the bundle file?

Comment: That's exactly what my code does, you can put any webpack configuration in there, where the comment says.

Comment: but which part it is where the bundle file is executed here?

Comment: Towards the end, the spawn statement

Comment: oh my bad dude, i did not see the comment properly. so in the webpack config part i specify the entry and output ?

Comment: i put the babel-loader to compile my es6 and stage-2 syntaxes in the config right?

Answer (score 1):

As for the babel part, I believe [babel loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) have you covered.  I use this in my `webpack.config.js` (webpack 2):

```
module: {
  ...
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {presets: ['es2015']}
    }
  ]
}
```

But I don't use nodemon, so sorry for just half an answer. I do use webpack-dev-server in development. and pm2 in staging/production and I'm using it's watch while staging so I don't have to restart things manually, and it's much easier to configure than webpacks dito:

```
// pm2's ecosystem.json (just to be thorough):
"watch"        : "./",
"ignore_watch" : "node_modules",
```

No watch in production though, no no, not me, no touchy - The less things that can go wrong the better.